# As a single-word enthusiast, what links/blogs should I follow?

Tags: discussion, resources

I am looking for resources to follow online for language and single-word hobbyists as myself. Do you have any good suggestions? Mailing list subscriptions, twitter feeds, etc?

Comment: Shouldn't there be a single word for "single-word hobbyists"?

Comment: monolexicologists?

Comment: [I just started searching](https://www.google.com/search?q=word+of+the+day) and there are many many possibilities, web pages, email, RSS feeds, twitter feeds, it just goes on and on. I'm making some into individual answers so that they can be voted on individually according to how good people think each one is.

Answer (score 4):

Merriam-Webster's [Word of the Day page](https://www.merriam-webster.com/word-of-the-day), where you can also subscribe to a daily email.

Answer (score 4):

[A Word A Day](https://wordsmith.org/words/today.html), and [a subscription for a daily email](https://wordsmith.org/awad/)

Answer (score 2):

The New York Times's [Word of the Day](https://www.nytimes.com/column/learning-word-of-the-day).

Answer (score 2):

[English Club](https://www.englishclub.com/vocabulary/word-of-the-day.htm) offers phrases, idioms, phrasal verbs.